# Calculate the inner angles of the triangle $A(2,-3,5),B(0,1,4),C(-2,5,2)$

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the inner angles of this triangle.
$$A(2,-3,5),B(0,1,4),C(-2,5,2)$$
I know that for calculate the angle I need to do the following thing:
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{A\cdot B}{|A||B|}$$
I need to calculate AB with BC and AC with AB and AC with BC?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
$$AB(-2,4,-1),AC(-4,8,-3),BC(-2,4,-2)$$
I found the angle between AB and AC = $5.94$
the angle between AC and BC = $5.55$
the angle between AB and BC is = $11.49$
the two other angles are right but the third not, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first calculate the vectors: $\overrightarrow{AB}$,  $\overrightarrow{BC}$, and  $\overrightarrow{AC}$, and their norms. After that use the formula you posted.

For example:
$$\overrightarrow{AB} = (0, 1,4)- (2,-3,5) = (-2, 4, -1)$$
$$|\overrightarrow{AB}|=\sqrt{(-2)^2+4^2+(-1)^2}.$$
I think you can conclude now.

**Edit**

The third angle you got is in fact an exterior angle. Using the dot product formula, you will get the angle between two vectors, when their representations are set sharing a common origin or a common end. See the picture bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the angle between any two vectors say $\overrightarrow a$ & $\overrightarrow b$ originated from the same point (i.e. tail-points coincident & heads directed away from the origin point) is calculated as $$\cos\alpha=\frac{\overrightarrow a \cdot \overrightarrow b  }{|\overrightarrow a||\overrightarrow b|}$$ Thus, keeping in mind the arrow directions of verctors,  all the angles are very easily calculated as follows

Angle $A$: between vectors $\overrightarrow {AB}=(-2, 4, -1)$ & $\overrightarrow {AC}=(-4, 8, -3)$ (heads directed away from the (origin) vertex A) is given as $$\angle A=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(-2)(-4)+(4)(8)+(-1)(-3)}{\left(\sqrt{(-2)^2+(4)^2+(-1)^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{(-4)^2+(8)^2+(-3)^2}\right)}\right)$$$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{43}{\sqrt{1869}}\right)\approx 5.94^o$$
Angle $B$: between vectors $\overrightarrow {BA}=(2, -4, 1)$ & $\overrightarrow {BC}=(-2, 4, -2)$ (heads directed away from the (origin) vertex B) is given as  $$\angle B=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(2)(-2)+(-4)(4)+(1)(-2)}{\left(\sqrt{(2)^2+(-4)^2+(1)^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{(-2)^2+(4)^2+(-2)^2}\right)}\right)$$$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-22}{\sqrt{504}}\right)=180^o-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{22}{\sqrt{504}}\right)\approx 168.51^o$$
Angle $C$: between vectors $\overrightarrow {CA}=(4, -8, 3)$ & $\overrightarrow {CB}=(2, -4, 2)$ (heads directed away from the (origin) vertex C) is given as  $$\angle C=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(4)(2)+(-8)(-4)+(3)(2)}{\left(\sqrt{(4)^2+(-8)^2+(3)^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{(2)^2+(-4)^2+(2)^2}\right)}\right)$$$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{46}{\sqrt{2136}}\right)\approx 5.55^o$$